# Is there any way to use just year and month as timestamp in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Specifically, I'd like to sort a column in a table in org-mode. However, the column only has year and month information, like 2016-02 or May 2016. It can't sort for now as it's not recognised as timestamp. How can I make it to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

An `org-mode` timestamp must have a day.  However if you give the months in the form "2016-02" then time sorting and alphabetical sorting are the same (so long as you're careful to keep everything padded to the same length).